# JPA, change field value using java on UPDATE/merge

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity with a field `updatedUser` which keeps track of the user who updated the row values.

When the entity is created this field is null but it should be set when a change is made to the entity and `merge` is used.

Is there some way, through java, to fill this value only when the entity has been updated? IE: should not be changed if it is created or retrieve from db.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees", uniqueConstraints= {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="idEmployees"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="idCardNumber"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="niNumber")
})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private int idEmployees;

    //other class variables

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="updatedEmployeeId")
    private Employee updatedEmployee;

    //constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a value is possbile by using the javax.persistence.PreUpdate annotation. But there is no way to inject the current user. Maybe it is possible to read the user from ThreadLocal and then set the user, but that is not a really clean solution as it must be set before when entering your business code or so ..

Comment: the current user will be handled when the user logs in. I just want to know if it's possible to set the field when updating.